# Kohana - Best way to pass an ORM object between controllers?

Tags: orm, controller, kohana-3, hmvc, kohana-orm

I have Model_Group that extends ORM.

I have Controller_Group that gets a new ORM:

```
public function before()
{
    global $orm_group;
    $orm_group = ORM::factory('Group');
}
```

...and it has various methods that use it to get different subsets of data, such as...

```
public function action_get_by_type()
{
    global $orm_group;
    $type = $this->request->param('type');
    $result = $orm_group->where('type', '=', $type)->find_all();
}
```

Then I have another controller (in a separate module) that I want to use to manipulate the object and call the relevant view. Let's call it Controller_Pages.

```
$orm_object = // Get the $result from Controller_Group somehow!
$this->template->content = View::factory( 'page1' )
    ->set('orm_object', $orm_object)
```

What is the best way to pass the ORM object from Controller_Group to Controller_Pages? Is this a good idea? If not, why not, and what better way is there of doing it?

The reason for separating them out into different controllers is because I want to be able to re-use the methods in Controller_Group from other modules. Each module may want to deal with the object in a different way.

Comment: I think the function `action_get_by_type` should be a function inside your ORM model. Than you can just call that function in every controller you want.

Comment: That's an interesting take on it. So do you mean I would call it by doing `$result = $orm_group->get_by_type($type);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it, but first I would like to note that you shouldn't use `global` in this context.

If you want to set your ORM model in the `before` function, just make a variable in your controller and add it like this.

```
public function before()
{
    $this->orm_group = ORM::factory('type');
}
```

In your `Model` your should also add the functions to access data and keep the controllers as small as possible. You ORM model could look something like this.

```
public class Model_Group extends ORM {
     //All your other code

     public function get_by_type($type)
     {
          return $this->where('type', '=', $type)->find_all();
     }
}
```

Than in your controllers you can do something like this.

```
public function action_index() 
{
     $type = $this->request->param('type');
     $result = $this->orm_group->get_by_type($type);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: **Thank you very much!** Also thank you for the pointer on using the global variable, I'm not sure why I had done that - just trying out different things!

Answer (score 1):

I always create an helper class for stuff like this

```
Class Grouphelper{
   public static function getGroupByType($type){
      return ORM::factory('Group')->where('type','=',$type)->find_all();
   }
}
```

Now you're been able to get the groups by type where you want:

```
Grouphelper::getGroupByType($type);
```

Comment: Also a valid and useful answer, thank you. I now need to have a think about which option is going to work best for me in the context of the application I'm building.